# Что такое AndroidX и зачем он?

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

В окне создания нового проекта появился чекбокс "Use AndroidX artefacts". Почитав об этом в интернете, я в целом так и не понял, что такое AndroidX. Объясните доступным языком, пожалуйста. И нужно ли включать его в новых проектах?

Comment: это то же, что и support library, но с новым названием и немного пересортированный по пакетам. проект еще местами в бете и переходить сейчас на использование вместо старых библиотек поддержки нет никакой острой необходимости

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AndroidX - это новая либа с новым пространством имён на замену support library API.

android.support 28.0.0 будет последним. Все что выше будет доступно только через androidx. Поэтому я бы советовал новые проекты сразу переносить или делать на androidX, а вот то что на продакшн как минимум выделить время и потестить.

Есть хорошие статьи по этому поводу, как крупные проекты мигрировали и допилвали своими скриптами.